# Remove based on duplicated field value, set based on parent field

Tags: apex, map, duplicate-management, set

I have a list of rules that are a detail record for requirements.  If any two rules have the same parent I would like to remove one of them from the list (doesn't matter which one).  I thought I could do this by creating a set, but am unsure of how to create the set based on the master-detail id, rather than the object id?

```
List<ProgramEligibilityRules__c> progrule = [SELECT Id, Requirement__c FROM ProgramEligibilityRules__c WHERE Id IN: reqs];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do it

```
Set<Id> uniqueReqIds = mew Set<Id>();
Map<Id, ProgramEligibilityRules__c> mapForUnique = new Map<Id, ProgramEligibilityRules__c>();

for (ProgramEligibilityRules__c> rule : [SELECT Id, Requirement__c FROM ProgramEligibilityRules__c WHERE Id IN: reqs]) {
  uniqueReqIds.add(rule.Requirement__c);
  mapForUnique.put(rule.Requirement__c, rule);
}
```

There.

The first Set will give you the unique reqs IDs. The Map will put one of the associated `ProgramEligibilityRules__c` record (the last) as the value.

Obviously, you don't need both. I just added them so you can pick the one you need.